# pytest-cov cover many applications at once

Tags: django, pytest, coverage.py, pytest-django

I built django project with many applications. Now I want to generate a coverage report for these applications.  For testing purposes, I use py.test, pytest-django and pytest-cov.  So far, I can generate the report only by typing all my app names manually on the command line:

```
py.test --cov-report html --cov=app1 --cov=app2 --cov=app3 --cov=app4 */tests.py
```

Does pytest-cov have a way to specify all the applications with a simple expression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're using bash, you could use it to expand the parameters:

```
py.test --cov-report html --cov=app{1,2,3,4} */tests.py
```

You could also add those parameters to `pytest.ini` so they're passed automatically on each invocation.

Comment: Yes, this approach solve my problem. Really I thought that in pytest-cov exist argument something like

`--cov=*` or `--cov=all`

for all installed apps, but really your solution is enough for me.

Answer (score 3):

@the-compiler 's answer did not work for me. If you want to test all apps, here is a way to do it:

```
pytest --cov-report html --cov=. */tests.py
```

source: https://medium.com/@harshvb7/using-pytest-to-write-tests-in-django-6783674c55b8

Comment: This one includes `.venv` directory

Comment: @freezed you can specify which folders to avoid in your `setup.cfg` ex: `norecursedirs = build docs/_build *.egg .tox *.venv *migrations* .*migrations* */migrations/*`

Answer (score 0):

### **Before**

[image]

[image]

### **After**

[image]

Change this line in ***pytest.ini***

```
python_files = tests.py test_*.py */tests_*.py
```

[image]

```
coverage run -m pytest
```